# How do I convert a Date String to a Timestamp with different date formats?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker.js plugin in an application. The plugin allow me to format the date to this: `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss` (10-09-2014 00:30:30) and I am trying to convert it to a timestamp so that I can use it in a sql statement. I am trying to use `TO_TIMSTAMP()` oracle function but when I try run the following line:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('10-09-2014 00:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss')
```

I get an execution error saying invalid month. Is there a step I a missing? I have tried to adjust the format of the bootstrap plugin but it does not return the documented result. Ant suggestions?

Comment: bootstrap datetimepicker uses momentjs in its core, so you can return UNIX timestamp like this: `new moment().format("X")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right month format will be MM instead MON:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('10-09-2014 00:30:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked out. The documentation for TO_TIMESTAMP() function made it appear that the formatting for the input to the function was only one way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

```
var date = new Date('10-09-2014 00:30:00');
date.getTime();
```

or just:

```
var timestamp = new Date('10-09-2014 00:30:00').getTime();
```